# Best method for inspecting Elastic Beanstalk JVM heap

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, jvm, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, heap-dump

I'm need to get a JVM heap dump from an Elastic Beanstalk server, but the server doesn't have jcmd or jmap. Amazon doesn't natively install them with the JDK. Here's what's installed:

```
[ec2-user@ip-x-x-x-x ~]$ sudo yum list installed|grep jdk
java-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64             1:1.7.0.111-2.6.7.2.68.amzn1 @amzn-updates
java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64             1:1.8.0.101-3.b13.24.amzn1   @amzn-updates
java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless.x86_64    1:1.8.0.101-3.b13.24.amzn1   @amzn-updates
```

What's the best way to get a heap dump from the JVM on Elastic Beanstalk?

Comment: Did you manage to get a heap dump from the JVM on EBS?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have found you can install jmap by installing the correct package:

```
sudo yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel
```

This should at least allow a heap dump to be generated.

In addition, to make sure all functions in jmap run, also install:

```
sudo yum --enablerepo='*-debug*' install java-1.8.0-openjdk-debuginfo
```

Although this might depend on the baseline, tomcat version etc you use.

When creating a heap dump, use the tomcat user:

```
sudo -u tomcat jmap -dump:live,file=/tmp/test.hprof <pid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Disclamer: I've never worked with Elastic Beanstalk, but I can recommend to check the following:

Consider taking the heap dump programmatically, I mean from within the Java application itself. There are many ways of doing that:

- Via JMX - the chances are that you'll find HotSpotDiagnostic bean and will be able to invoke the heap dump operation ([Here](http://blog.bosch-si.com/categories/technology/2011/11/how-to-get-a-heap-dump-of-a-remote-machine-via-jmx/) there is a tutorial for doing this)
- If your application is new and you have Spring Boot, then probably its possible to plug Spring Actuator that has a "/heapdump" endpoint just for this purpose