# How to get heap dump from aws elastic beanstalk environment

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, out-of-memory, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We are getting OutOfMemoryError from a spring boot application running inside tomcat container hosted in aws elastic beanstalk. So how do i get heap dump from elastic beanstalk ?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48110954/7024630
The above answer suggests a method by installing third-party dependency to get heap dump, is there any way around to get directly from AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Best method for inspecting Elastic Beanstalk JVM heap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44650942/best-method-for-inspecting-elastic-beanstalk-jvm-heap/48110954#48110954), it's worked for me.

In my case, I using a java 7:

```
$ which java
$ ls -lh /usr/bin/java
$ yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel
$ yum --enablerepo='*-debug*' install java-1.7.0-openjdk-debuginfo
$ ps aux | grep tomcat
$ sudo -u tomcat jmap -dump:live,file=/tmp/test.hprof 12768
$ tar -czvf test.hprof.tar.gz /tmp/test.hprof
$ scp test.hprof.tar.gz xxxxxxxxxxxxx@x.y.z.w:~/
```